# how to add the above row x times in excel based on the number y which can change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make an excel file for my parents so that they have it easier than writing all the info in a book X amount of times.

i have A; B; C; D; E; F; G; H; I; J; and L columns and want to automate and duplicate the data in A to G in rows below xn-1 times when

there is a number on Hx cell x amount of times,

where x can be from 1 to 50.

https://preview.redd.it/8p19v7ncjyo91.png?width=1859&format=png&auto=webp&s=5265abb1f6c77b418c409197e19ab836f62bd5ec
before typing 10

https://preview.redd.it/xq9p3m69kyo91.png?width=1384&format=png&auto=webp&s=b06512811b45d8d7c33ff8072d58bc1f8603fa46

example data after inputting 10 or 5 respectively

thus will be inputting all the details in rows 17 and 27

Comment: What version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Do you know the `Offset()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. It iterates backwards, inserts the necessary number of rows (from "H" cell) and copy on them the values of between columns "A:G" of the row where "H" cell is not empty and numeric:

```
Sub CopyRowsNTimes()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRH As Long, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet  'use here the sheet you need
   lastRH = sh.Range("H" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on column "H:H")
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   For i = lastRH To 2 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(sh.Range("H" & i).Value) And sh.Range("H" & i).Value <> "" Then
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            sh.rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + sh.Range("H" & i).Value - 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            sh.Range("A" & i + 1, "G" & i + 1 + sh.Range("H" & i).Value - 2).Value = _
                 sh.Range("A" & i, "G" & i).Value
        End If
   Next i
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

I think, clearing the content of H:H column after processing will be a good idea. For the case you run the code for the second time, by mistake. I let it as it was, only to easily check the inserted rows...

Answer (score 0):

### Duplicate Rows

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    DuplicateRows Target, "H2", 1, 50
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateRows( _
        ByVal TargetCell As Range, _
        ByVal CriteriaColumnFirstCellAddress As String, _
        Optional ByVal MinTargetValue As Long = 1, _
        Optional ByVal MaxTargetValue As Long = 1)
    Const ProcName As String = "DuplicateRows"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Validate 'TargetCell'.
    
    'If TargetCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If TargetCell.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' not a single cell
    
    ' Validate 'CriteriaColumnFirstCellAddress'.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = TargetCell.Worksheet
    
    Dim fCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set fCell = ws.Range(CriteriaColumnFirstCellAddress)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' invalid address
    If fCell.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' not a single cell
    
    ' Build the Criteria (one-column) range ('crg').
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    Dim crg As Range
    With fCell
        Set crg = Intersect(rg, .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1))
    End With
    If crg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' not intersecting
    If Intersect(TargetCell, crg) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' not intersecting
    
    ' Validate 'MinTargetValue' and 'MaxTargetValue'.
    
    If MinTargetValue < 1 Then Exit Sub
    If MaxTargetValue < 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim MinValue As Long
    Dim MaxValue As Long
    ' Handle if min and max are switched.
    If MinTargetValue < MaxTargetValue Then
        MinValue = MinTargetValue
        MaxValue = MaxTargetValue
    Else
        MinValue = MaxTargetValue
        MaxValue = MinTargetValue
    End If
    
    ' Validate the Target value.
        
    Dim TargetValue As Variant: TargetValue = TargetCell.Value
    If Not VarType(TargetValue) = vbDouble Then Exit Sub ' not a number
    If Int(TargetValue) <> TargetValue Then Exit Sub ' not a whole number
    Select Case TargetValue
        Case MinValue To MaxValue
        Case Else: Exit Sub ' exceeds the range of numbers
    End Select
    
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = Intersect(rg, TargetCell.EntireRow)
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = crg.Cells(crg.Cells.Count).Row
    Dim MaxInsertRows As Long: MaxInsertRows = ws.Rows.Count - LastRow
    If TargetValue > MaxInsertRows Then Exit Sub ' doesn't fit in the worksheet
    
    ' (Insert) Copy the data.
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    With rrg
        If .Row < LastRow Then
            .Offset(1).Resize(TargetValue).Insert _
                Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
        TargetCell.ClearContents
        .Copy Destination:=.Resize(TargetValue + 1)
    End With
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        With Application
            If Not .EnableEvents Then .EnableEvents = True
            If Not .ScreenUpdating Then .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```